# Grape Entity - how can I return the nested value instead of the key value pair?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, ruby-grape

I have a POST auth endpoint that returns a token and user object data, along with some metadata.

Im running into an issue because I am not trying to return an object from my Entity, I just want to return a value...

**here is a sample JSON response from my endpoint:**

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "request_time": 0.108006,
  "records": 1,
  "msg": "some msg",
  "user": {
    "id": "someidstringformongodb",
    "created_at": "2017-07-10T17:15:15.334-07:00",
    "updated_at": "2017-07-10T17:15:15.334-07:00",
    "active": true,
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "suffix": null,
    "title": "Cool Title",
    "admin": false,
    "phone": "777-777-7777"
  },
  "access_key": {
    "token": "xxxsomerandomtokenxxx"
  }
}
```

**desired JSON response**

```
{
  // ...
  "user": {
    //...
  },
  "access_key": "xxxsomerandomtokenxxx"
}

// or

{
  // ...
  "user": {
    //...
  },
  "token": "xxxsomerandomtokenxxx"
}
```

**relevant endpoint code**

```
post '/' do
  email_pattern = /^#{ sanitize_user_input(params[:email]) }$/i
  user = SomeModule::User.find_by(email: email_pattern)
  error!('Invalid email/password combination') if user.nil?
  error!('Invalid email/password combination') unless user.password == params[:password]
  error!('This account is no longer active') unless user.active
  access_key = SomeModule::AccessKey.new_key_for_user(user)
  access_key.save
  present_success user, "some msg"
  present :user, user, with: SomeModule::Entities::UserBase

  ## what should happen to this, in order to return only the value instead of an object?
  present :access_key, access_key, with: SomeModule::Entities::AccessKey
end
```

**relevant entity code**

```
class AccessKey < Grape::Entity
  expose :token
end
```

Comment: why dont you just write a searlizer for this

Comment: @TasawarHussain what is a serializer? is it a grape specific feature or ruby?